# c++ search for string in an vector of strings

Tags: c++, string, vector

I am working on a project to read a Context-free Grammar and represent it 1.Vectorial, 2. Branched chained lists, 3. Array (Table). I encounter a problem with string comparison. When I read a string from keyboard representing right side of a Production rule, I want to check if that string exists in a vector of strings. The problem is that comparison is not working right. If the string I compare is the first string from the vector of strings than the comparison is working fine. But if the string I compare is a string from the vector of strings other than first comparison is not working, it's like the string is not from the vector of strings. Sorry for my English. I better let the code explain

```
bool is(string &s, vector<string> &v) {
    for (auto i : v) {
        return (i.compare(s)==0) ? true : false;
    }
}
```

This function returns true only if s=v[0], otherwise returns false even if s=v[2]

Comment: `is` always returns in the first loop iteration.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question so that it meets all requirements for a [mre], as explained in the [help]? See [ask] for more information. Until everyone can take your [mre], then cut and paste it ***exactly as shown***, run it, and reproduce your results, it is unlikely that anyone will be able to tell you anything.

Comment: Lets take only the is function. If s = v[0] my function returns true. if s is anything else, even s=v[2] my function return false

Comment: Note the existence of [`std::find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find). And `[some conditional expression] ? true : false` is always redundant.

Comment: It would work except you are always returning ferm the loop the first thime through.  The return is not conditional so it always returns the comparison of the first item of the array.  Change the function to `bool is(const string &s, const vector<string> &v) { for (auto i : v) { if(i.compare(s)==0) return true; } return false; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do that you'd have to loop into the vector with a for loop and compare every string in it, it would be something like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

bool doExists(string s, vector<string> v) {
    for (int i=0;i<v.size();i++) {
        if (s.compare(v[i]) == 0) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

int main(){
    vector<string> phrases = {"Hello!", "I like potatos!","I like fries.","How are you today?","I'm good.","Hello!"};
    int helloLocated = doExists("Hello!", phrases);
    cout << helloLocated;
}
```

The console would print 1.